# Using Fullcalendar with bootstrap model External Links

Tags: fullcalendar

http://jsfiddle.net/manking/6wd5fg74/

Trying to use the data set from a fullcalendar  to open modal window with an external link. Just pops up a blank modal window. I am sure that I am not coding the script just right .

I want to have a list of external links that can use the same json data in the fullcalendar and open the modal window.

```
<div class="menu">
<a href="http://example.org" id="0DE2162E-155D-6942-02BED53F1B281FE2">Example</a>
<a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable" href="load_page.cfm?method=get-page-content&amp;page=12" data-toggle="modal"  id="0DE2162E-155D-6942-02BED53F1B281FE2"><div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">8a</span> <span class="fc-title">My Birthday</span></div></a></div>




<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            events: [{
    "id": "0DE2162E-155D-6942-02BED53F1B281FE2",
    "url": "load_page.cfm?method=get-page-content&page=10",
    "title": "test",
    "description": "<p><span style=\"color:rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:arial,helvetica,sans; font-size:11px; line-height:14px; text-align:justify\">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</span></p>",
    "start": "2015-05-19T08:00",
    "end": "2015-05-19T08:59",
    "allday": false   
  },{
    "id": "0A2C0875-155D-6942-02D0F17291318096",
    "url": "load_page.cfm?method=get-page-content&page=12",
    "title": "My Birthday",
    "description": ",<p>Happy Birthday</p>",
    "start": "2015-05-13T08:00",
    "end": "2015-05-13T08:59",
    "allday": false   
  }],
            eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
                $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
                $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
                $('#fullCalModal').modal();
                return false;
            },

            loading: function(bool) {
                if (bool) {
                    $('#loading').show();
                }else{
                    $('#loading').hide();
                }
            }
        });

    });

jQuery( 'div.menu a' )
    .click(  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
                $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
                $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
                $('#fullCalModal').modal();
                return false;
            });

});//]]>  

</script>

<div class="menu">
    <a href="http://example.org" id="0DE2162E-155D-6942-02BED53F1B281FE2">Example</a>
    <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable" href="load_page.cfm?method=get-page-content&amp;page=12" data-toggle="modal"  id="0DE2162E-155D-6942-02BED53F1B281FE2"><div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">8a</span> <span class="fc-title">My Birthday</span></div></a></div>
<div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">x</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
                    <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary"><a id="eventUrl" target="_blank">Event Page</a></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: what u want to do.. do you want to show the event details in the modal popup or what?? Make it brief..

Comment: I edited my original post to add what I was looking to do.

Comment: I'm not sure if you still have a question of if you answered your question within the question. Do you still have some issue? If so, please clarify what is not working. From what I understood, you want a list of links outside the calendar to open a modal dialog with the corresponding event data. If so, it appears (from your jsfiddle) that you got that working. If you solved your issue, please do not update your question. Instead, post a answer describing how you solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See http://fiddle.jshell.net/manking/6wd5fg74/ for code answer. This is how to use external links and in calendar links to access modal window.

Comment: The link is broken